# Do Amazon (or any vendor) reviews count as a gauge for recommendations?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

Can the hardware recommendations be justified/done taking Amazon reviews into account?

For example: Questions like [these](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/267/laptop-for-front-end-development) which has an answer where multiple recommendations end in a tie with respect to the OP's desired specs.

So, in that case, can the answer cite Amazon(or vendor) ratings as a tie breaker and recommend the product with better rating?

Such answers look like an obvious possibility in the future, so wanted to confirm the possible consequences.

Would that answer be considered genuine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any reason *not* to include Amazon reviews in an answer, but we have to remember: **You should have personal experience with a product** before you recommend it.

We shouldn't be a site that just searches for the title of the question and throws up an answer with a couple Amazon reviews taped on. We want to have answers from people that have actually used the product, not people who read some stuff written by people who actually used the product.

Comment: I completely agree with this, but there's a downside here: If someone's asking about a very obscure or technical piece of hardware, there may never be anyone here who has the experience to answer.

Comment: @Adam That's okay IMO, we've had the same problem on SR. I'd rather have unanswered questions than questions with low-quality answers.